# Difference between .a .o and .lo file

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, libraries

What is the difference between `.a` `.o` and `.lo` file in C?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[The '.lo' file is a library object](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/libtool/libtool_8.html), which may be built into a shared library, and the '.o' file is a standard object file

[The .lo file is the libtool object](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Creating-object-files.html), which Libtool uses to determine what object file may be built into a shared library

Comment: Does that mean .o files CANNOT be built into a shared library?

Comment: @Raj Kumar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583770/making-shared-library-from-exist-o-files

Comment: Do you really want all of your answer to be in the form of links?

Comment: @Raj no it does not, that naming is convenience, not requirement.

Answer (score 110):

## Difference Between .o, .a, .lo and .so.

### Executive Summary

- *.o* is typically a non-PIC object file emitted by the compiler (before linker stage)  When linked with an exe, the code will be included in the executable -- we bind at link time.
- *.a* is typically an archive library containing one or more *.o* files [non-PIC].  When linked with an exe, the particular "*.o" files in the archive will be inserted into the executable.
- *.lo* is generally a "library object" that contains PIC code whether manually compiled with *gcc -fPIC* or using *libtool*.
- *.so* files are "shared object" files. They contains PIC objects.

**Note:**

- If you need static executables then use ".o" and ".a" files.
- If you need/want dynamic executables the bind with libraries at run time, use *.lo* and *.so* files.

### Introduction

While I like the answers above, they do not cover the .a/archive library form.  So here I will address all three with a bonus of adding in a .so library format, as well.  Also, in the vein of stackexchange, I will use more text in case links get broken (note that I did not need reference links for this one).

### Filetype .o

When compiling a *.o* file is an object file containing the compiler emitted object code for the target platform.  To create a *.o* file:

```
gcc -c filename.c     <==== creates filename.o
```

Note that this example did not create Position Independent Code (PIC).  We consider this an object for possible inclusion in a static library or executable.  That is, when we link an executable with a *.o* file, the code in the .o file is inserted into the executable --- it is bound at build time, not at run time.  That means the executable can be redistributed without including the .o file.  Caveat:  it is convention that the *.o* file is considered non-PIC.  We typically name PIC object files with a *.lo* extension.

### Filetype .a

The *.a* file type is an "**archive**" library.  It contains one or more .o files and it is typically used to for creating static executable files.

We use the *ar* command to manipulate archive libraries.  Below in an example that (1) creates an archive library from *.o* files then (2) lists the contents of one.

**Create the Library**

```
$ ls *.o
a.o  b.o  c.o                 <=== the files going in the archive

$ ar q libmyStuff.a *.o       <=== put *.o files in an archive (or new one)
ar: creating libmyStuff.a    

$ ls *.a                      <=== just show the library created
libmyStuff.a
```

**Display the Contents of an Archive Library**

```
$ ar t libmyStuff.a
a.o
b.o
c.o
```

### Filetype .lo

The use of *.lo* is a convention that is often used for position independent object files.  In the current directory the  *libtool compile* command creates both a *.lo* file and a *.o* file, one with PIC code and one without PIC code.  See the output below:

```
$ libtool compile gcc -c a.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -c a.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/a.o  <== PIC code
libtool: compile:  gcc -c a.c -o a.o >/dev/null 2>&1     <== Not-PIC code

$ ls a.lo a.o
a.lo  a.o       <=== a.lo contains the PIC code.
```

Also note that the *.libs* subdirectory was created with *a.o* in it.  This file is PIC code, despite the name.  *Libtool* moved this file to the current directory and changed the extension to *.lo*.

You can always manually create *.lo* files simply by using the PIC option(s) to gcc when you compile.  Move the resulting *.o* files to *.lo* extension.

### Filetype .so

By convention .so implies a "shared object" library file.  We put PIC object files into shared libraries.  In contract to *.o* and *.a* files, when we link with *.so* files the code is not included in the resulting compiled file.  That is we use run time binding (as in the *.lo* case).  There is more than one form of runtime binding, but we won't go into that here.

Comment: Is there a book that covers the type of information that you have explained in your answer? I can only locate useful practical information like your post in forums, etc. The knowledge is fragmented and never presented as a coherent coverage of how programs are built and run.

Comment: Nope. *.lo files are human readable, plain text files that contain name of pic object and non_pic object. PIC code is usually in `.libs/a.o` and  and nonPIC is in `a.o`. So libtool creates 3 files: 2 object files (`.o`), one PIC and one not + `.lo` file which describes where the files are.

Comment: @wandadars: Check out "Linkers and Loaders" by John R. Levine https://linker.iecc.com/

Comment: This is a much higher quality answer, and should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 3):

The `.lo` file is a library object, which may be built into a shared library, and the `.o` file is a standard object file.    More info: [How to install and use libtool shared library (.lo files)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985881/how-to-install-and-use-libtool-shared-library-lo-files)

Comment: Does that mean .o files CANNOT be built into a shared library?

Comment: The most important technical difference is that a .lo-file should contain relocatable code (-fPIC in GCC), whereas a .o-file might not.